# Best build for pure caster

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm fairly new to Dark Souls 2. I am just wondering what stats/gear I should aim towards. I want my character to be a pure caster using sorceries, hexes, pyromancies, miracles, and maybe a bit of bows or crossbows for those hard to reach enemies. My current character is wearing melee gear, sword shield, that sort of thing. Early game is near impossible without a shield I've found so far.

Any help would be appreciated. I am currently farming the starter areas outside the pursuer boss zone. Should I keep focusing on melee gear until I can re-spec for magic stuff?

Main focus would be SL150 probably won't do new game plus, winning the game once is enough for me, so far I like pyro and sorcereys, I'd like to throw some miracles in there if possible, I looked over all the gear you guys listed for me to aim towards, on a side note what should I try get to help me reach the end of the game, remember im still in the beginning basically

Comment: This is kind of an offshoot to your question but you should have a little easier time early game by using the dagger. It has low stat requirements and the backstab damage will kill most enemies up until you cab use dark orb

Comment: "Best build" recommendations are too broad. If you could define what level requirement you are looking at (100? 150? Max?) and you have only defined "Caster", which does not narrow it down at all. Which strain of magic? Pyro? Faith? Sorcery? Dark? What you are currently asking is for us to compare, well, the entire game for you, and tell you what we think is best. And that leads into "Primarily opinion based".

Answer (score -1):

Here is a reference from [the wiki](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/characterbuild:hex-blasting-pure-mage)

Starting Class  Sorcerer

Level   150

Vigor   20

Endurance   15

Vitality    15

Attunement  40

Strength    3

Dexterity   7

Adaptability    10

Intelligence    46

Faith   47

Weapons

Right Hand:
Dark Sunset Staff +5
Binoculars

Left hand:
Dark Chime of Want +5 (short range)
Lightning Dragon Chime +5 (long range)

Equipment

Hexer's Hood +5
Hever's Gloves +5
Velstadt's Armor +5
Velstadt's Legs +5

Third Dragon Ring
Chloranthy Ring +2
Clear Bluestone Ring +2
Southern Ritual Band +2

Spells

Great Lightning Spear x2 (PvE) -or- Sun Spear (PvP)
Dark Orb x2 (PvE) -or- Resonant Soul (PvP)
Scraps of Life
Dark Fog
Dark Storm
Soul Greatsword (If you have the slots, depends on whether you got the +2 southern ritual band)

Tips

PvE tactics for this build are fairly straightforward. Utilize your bottomless pit of dark orbs to ruin everything in front of you. With these stats and this equipment, each orb will do in the ballpark of 500-800 damage depending on the enemy, and you'll be capable of casting one every 1.5 seconds. You have plenty of other tactics to use, like using scraps of life to maintain separation on a horde of enemies, or using your other bottomless pit of lightning spears to snipe enemies from a safe distance. Dark Fog is also very very useful in certain situations, mainly against stationary targets like enemy mages or shield using slow opponents. For example, poisoning a Syan Knight will kill it outright, just wait a minute. Dark storm is fairly situational in PvE, and is best used in coop. This spell is also the reason you want to be wearing heavy armor, because you are nearly guaranteed to take hits while using it, but the damage an enemy will take while attacking you is almost always worth the trade (it generally kills things outright).

PvP requires an extension of the PvE tactics above, but you must be much more savvy in your casting, and faster. Success is rarely instantaneous (no crazy one shot backstabs in this class), but you can almost always impose your will and win a protracted battle. Using spells in combination is key, and you must always keep the pressure on. If you're facing a heavy melee opponent, using scraps of life to maintain separation is extremely important. If you manage to score a hit (which will knock them down) follow up immediately with dark fogs to inflict poison. Or, if you're facing a fast melee opponent, bait them in with dark storm, and follow immediately with a soul greatsword if they are smart enough to not rush into the storm. If the fight is long range against a mage or archer, Dark fog followed by sun spears usually wins the fight quickly. You may want to substitute the Sun spears for Crystal Soul Spear, as that seems to land hit [more often in PvP.](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/characterbuild:hex-blasting-pure-mage)

Comment: Can you add in something that's not just a pure copy and paste from elsewhere, please?  It's great that you've added attribution, but it's a good idea to add some original content as well.

Comment: Ok will do next time Frank.

Comment: Also I noticed this build recommends bino's in the right hand. Is this a 'bino-boost' build? Because that has been long since patched.

Comment: @Ben nope Bino is a very good item if you use Magic. You can Cast while holding the binos which is good because you can kind of aim with that set up (very good for long range cast).